# How to call ui bootstrap modal popup controller from within angular js another controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

how can i call angular ui bootstrap modal popup from inside another controller , as the condition is like instead of calling from view i need to call it from inside a function

```
       App.controller('MailFolderController', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$stateParams', '$window', 'mails', '$interval', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $stateParams, $window, mails, $interval) {


     $scope.check = function(){
console.log("call parent ==========>")
     // call open method in modal popup here  
   }


    App.controller('orderCancellationController', ['$scope', '$modal', function ($scope, $modal) {

$scope.open = function (mail) {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '/orderCancellationBox.html',
        controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
        resolve: {
            mail: function () {
                return mail;
            }
        }
    });
};

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, mail) {

    $scope.mail = mail;
    $scope.submit = function () {
        $scope.$parent.check();
        $modalInstance.close('closed');
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
};
ModalInstanceCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "$modalInstance", 'mail'];

 }]);


}]);
```

so i want to call the open method in orderCancellationController from inside the check method , help !!

Comment: Take a look at this question ->  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086854/angular-calling-modal-open-function-from-one-controller-to-another

Comment: My first suggestion would be to create a service that handles your modal open service if you don't want to copy paste your code.

Comment: @NotKnown How Armin already said, take the code for modal dialog in a service.

Comment: can anybody please elaborate , i m not getting exactly , like how the orderCancellatioController will bind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the example from my comment: [Angular Calling Modal Open function from one controller to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086854/angular-calling-modal-open-function-from-one-controller-to-another)

In order to open the modal from another controller you have to create a service, I did so in my app.js file, like so:

```
myApp.service('modalProvider',['$modal', function ($modal) {

this.openPopupModal = function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '/orderCancellationBox.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl'
    });
};
}]);
```

Then in the controller I wish to open my modal from, I inject the 'modalProvider' service, like so:

```
 App.controller('MailFolderController', ['$scope', '$http', '$timeout', '$stateParams', '$window', 'mails', '$interval','modalProvider', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $stateParams, $window, mails, $interval, modalProvider) {

// function to open modal
 $scope.check = function(){
    modalProvider.openPopupModal();
}
```